# Fourier representation of function, that is similar to Taylor expansion.

Tags: fourier-series

Here is the function: $f(x) = \frac{x^3}{3}+x$, $-\pi \le x \le \pi$, period: $2\pi$

I tried to compute the coefficients, but noticed that the integral for coef. $a_n$ looks labourous and there might be some catch. Is it computable the usual way or somehow else? ( I am not asking for integral computations)
$$a_0 = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int^{\pi}_{-\pi}f(x) dx = \frac{1}{2\pi} \left[\frac{x^4}{12}+\frac{1}{2}x^2  \right]^{\pi}_{-\pi} = 0 \\ a_n = \frac{1}{\pi}\int^{\pi}_{-\pi} \left(\sin (\frac{\pi x n}{\pi}) \right)(\frac{1}{3}x^3+x)dx$$

Comment: @copper.hat Here I edited the post, it's $x$.

Comment: The integral actually isn't that bad if you know a neat trick called [tabular integration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yyic5aaXGaw).